# Open source tools for comparing baseline/benchmark to subsequent performance test runs

Tags: time-series, performance-testing, benchmarking, gatling, locust

I did some research around open-source tools that can be used to compare current/benchmarked performance test results against performance tests being run in the future, but I could not find any. I am planning to use this with gatling and locust based tests.

Basically, the flow is:

- Run a test and capture a baseline.
- Now for every subsequent run, compare the server and client metrics (example: p99, p95 latencies, error rate, CPU/Memory utilization of the application under test etc) with the baseline.
- Incase of delta beyond an acceptable tolerance factor, throw an alert(can write some scripts to do this and throw alerts on slack/email)

Is there any solution available that does this?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure regarding tools you're trying to use, but [Apache JMeter](https://jmeter.apache.org/) has:

- [Merge Results Plugin](https://jmeter-plugins.org/wiki/MergeResults/) which is basically intended for different test runs comparison
- [Jenkins Performance Plugin](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/jenkins-performance-plugin) which provides performance trend chart out of the box and has possibility to mark the build as unstable or failed if the performance got worse comparing to the reference(baseline) build or to previous build

Tool-agnostic approach: you should be able to save the results into CSV file or a database and then use i.e. [Grafana](https://grafana.com/) to build whatever charts you want and define whatever alerts you need

Answer (score 0):

[locust-plugins dashboards](https://github.com/SvenskaSpel/locust-plugins/blob/master/locust_plugins/dashboards/README.md) has basic functionality for tracking/graphing requests/s, average response time and test status over time.

It could be extended to track other metrics too.

It uses TimescaleDB as backend and Grafana dashboards for graphing.